# Where would I ask a question about a GAME crashing MY COMPUTER multiple times when I try to launch it?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I'm wondering where I should ask a question regarding Fortnite crashing my entire computer when I try to launch it. When the game "launches," it just doesn't actually launch and instead makes my computer return a "System-Thread-Exception" error.

I don't know if I should ask it on Arqade since it is about a game crash or if I should ask it on some software site since it is the computer, not the game, crashing.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think any site in the Stack Exchange will be of help. Maybe try Fortnite's official forums.

Comment: @Renan the thing is, I think I know my problem: for some reason it can't handle multiple accounts I think but I don't know a fix. So, the forums wouldn't help; but thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds like a question for Super User. See the [bsod](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsod) tag. (You should post the question with the exact error message, stack trace, and memory dump, if possible.)

Comment: Nice to know that we have something like that.